# Get a new column (consensus of element in others) with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need some help using pandas data frames.
Here is the data frame:

```
group   col1    col2    name
1       dog     40      canidae
1       dog     40      canidae
1       dog     40      canidae
1       dog     40      canidae
1       dog     40  
1       dog     40      canidae
1       dog     40      canidae
2       frog    85      dendrobatidae
2       frog    89      leptodactylidae
2       frog    89      leptodactylidae
2       frog    82      leptodactylidae
2       frog    89 
2       frog    81 
2       frog    89      dendrobatidae
3       horse   87      equidae1
3       donkey  76      equidae2
3       zebra   67      equidae3
4       bird    54      psittacidae
4       bird    56  
4       bird    34  
5       bear    67    
5       bear    54
```

What I would like to get is to add a column "consensus_name" an get :

```
group col1   col2 name              consensus_name
1     dog    40   canidae           canidae
1     dog    40   canidae           canidae
1     dog    40                     canidae
1     dog    40   canidae           canidae
1     dog    40   canidae           canidae
2     frog   85   dendrobatidae     leptodactylidae
2     frog   89   leptodactylidae   leptodactylidae
2     frog   89   leptodactylidae   leptodactylidae
2     frog   82   leptodactylidae   leptodactylidae
2     frog   89                     leptodactylidae
2     frog   81                     leptodactylidae
2     frog   89   dendrobatidae     leptodactylidae
3     horse  87   equidae1          equidae3
3     donkey 76   equidae2          equidae3
3     zebra  67   equidae3          equidae3
4     bird   54   psittacidae       psittacidae
4     bird   56                     psittacidae
4     bird   34                     psittacidae
5     bear   67                     NA
5     bear   54                     NA
```

In order to get this new column for each group, I get the name which is the most representative of the group.

- For the `group1` there are 4 rows with the name `'canidae'` and one with nothing, so for each one I write `'canidae'` in the column `consensus_name`
- For the `group2` there are 2 rows with the name `'dendrobatidae'`, 2 with nothing and 3 rows with the name `'leptodactylidae'` so for each one I write '`leptodactylidae'` in the column `consensus_name`.
- For the `group3` there are 3 rows with different names, so because there is no consensus, I get the name which as the lowest `col2` number, so I write `'equidae3'` in the column `consensus_name`.
- For the group 4 only one row have an information, so it is the consensus_name of the `group4`, so I write `psittacidae` in the column `consensus_name`.
- For the `group5` there is none informations, then just write NA in the `consensus_name` column.

Does anyone have any idea to do it with pandas ? Thank for your help :)

---

Output for anky =

```
    group    col1  col2             name   consensus_name
0       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
1       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
2       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
3       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
4       1     dog    40              NaN          canidae
5       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
6       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
7       2    frog    85    dendrobatidae    dendrobatidae
8       2    frog    89  leptodactylidae  leptodactylidae
9       2    frog    89  leptodactylidae  leptodactylidae
10      2    frog    82  leptodactylidae  leptodactylidae
11      2    frog    89              NaN  leptodactylidae
12      2    frog    81              NaN  leptodactylidae
13      2    frog    89    dendrobatidae    dendrobatidae
14      3   horse    87         equidae1         equidae1
15      3  donkey    76         equidae2         equidae2
16      3   zebra    67         equidae3         equidae3
17      4    bird    54      psittacidae      psittacidae
18      4    bird    56              NaN      psittacidae
19      4    bird    34              NaN      psittacidae
20      5    bear    67              NaN              NaN
21      5    bear    54              NaN              NaN
```

Comment: `df['consensus_name']=df.groupby(['group','col1'])['name'].apply(lambda x:x.ffill().bfill())` ??

Comment: @anky_91 hello, thank you but I do not get a consensus for `equidae3` (`group3`), I should get the name wich has the lowest `col2` value. And in the group2, not all individus have the consensus name `leptodactylidae`, the line `13` kept the `dendrobatidae` name...

Comment: Why is this question tagged with Python and pandas while you're asking to have a solution in R ?

Comment: @Guybrush it was a mistake from me, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to define your own function. Make sure to replace the empty strings with `NaN` so they are never considered. `transform` can get tricky with calculations based on multiple columns, so instead groupby and map the result back to the original.

```
import numpy as np

def my_mode(gp):
    s = gp['name'].value_counts()
    s = s[s.eq(s.max())]

    if len(s) == 0:      # If all missing
        return np.NaN
    elif len(s) == 1:    # If there is a mode without ties
        return s.index[0]
    else:                # If ties, use the one with min col2 
        return gp.loc[gp['name'].isin(s.index)].sort_values('col2')['name'].iloc[0]
```

---

```
df['name'] = df['name'].replace({'': np.NaN})
df['consensus_name'] = df['group'].map(df.groupby('group').apply(my_mode))
```

#### Output:

```
    group    col1  col2             name   consensus_name
0       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
1       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
2       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
3       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
4       1     dog    40              NaN          canidae
5       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
6       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
7       2    frog    85    dendrobatidae  leptodactylidae
8       2    frog    89  leptodactylidae  leptodactylidae
9       2    frog    89  leptodactylidae  leptodactylidae
10      2    frog    82  leptodactylidae  leptodactylidae
11      2    frog    89              NaN  leptodactylidae
12      2    frog    81              NaN  leptodactylidae
13      2    frog    89    dendrobatidae  leptodactylidae
14      3   horse    87         equidae1         equidae3
15      3  donkey    76         equidae2         equidae3
16      3   zebra    67         equidae3         equidae3
17      4    bird    54      psittacidae      psittacidae
18      4    bird    56              NaN      psittacidae
19      4    bird    34              NaN      psittacidae
20      5    bear    67              NaN              NaN
21      5    bear    54              NaN              NaN
```

---

The only edge case we haven't explicitly defined is what happens when there is a tie for the modal value **and** they tie for the minimum of col2. Currently it will choose the name with the lowest index (the one that occurs first in the DataFrame) in those situations.

Comment: @chippycentra this should be the accepted answer. My answer wont work in all cases as pointed out. I cannot remove my answer as long as its accepted as answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time it works very well :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.Groupby.Series.transform` and pass it the `max` function:

```
#First fillna with empty string
df.name.fillna('', inplace=True)

df['consensus_name'] = df.groupby('group').name.transform('max')

print(df)
    group    col1  col2             name   consensus_name
0       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
1       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
2       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
3       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
4       1     dog    40                           canidae
5       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
6       1     dog    40          canidae          canidae
7       2    frog    85    dendrobatidae  leptodactylidae
8       2    frog    89  leptodactylidae  leptodactylidae
9       2    frog    89  leptodactylidae  leptodactylidae
10      2    frog    82  leptodactylidae  leptodactylidae
11      2    frog    89                   leptodactylidae
12      2    frog    81                   leptodactylidae
13      2    frog    89    dendrobatidae  leptodactylidae
14      3   horse    87         equidae1         equidae3
15      3  donkey    76         equidae2         equidae3
16      3   zebra    67         equidae3         equidae3
17      4    bird    54      psittacidae      psittacidae
18      4    bird    56                       psittacidae
19      4    bird    34                       psittacidae
20      5    bear    67                                  
21      5    bear    54
```

**Edit** after pointed out not generally apply-able:

```
df['name'] = df.groupby('group').name.ffill()

df_group = df.groupby('group').name.apply(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x, dropna=False)).reset_index()
df_group = df_group[df_group.level_1 == df_group.groupby('group').level_1.transform('max')]
df_group.rename({'name':'consensus_name'},axis=1, inplace=True)

df_final = pd.merge(df, df_group, on='group')

print(df_final)
    group    col1  col2             name  level_1   consensus_name
0       1     dog    40          canidae        0          canidae
1       1     dog    40          canidae        0          canidae
2       1     dog    40          canidae        0          canidae
3       1     dog    40          canidae        0          canidae
4       1     dog    40          canidae        0          canidae
5       1     dog    40          canidae        0          canidae
6       1     dog    40          canidae        0          canidae
7       2    frog    85    dendrobatidae        0  leptodactylidae
8       2    frog    89  leptodactylidae        0  leptodactylidae
9       2    frog    89  leptodactylidae        0  leptodactylidae
10      2    frog    82  leptodactylidae        0  leptodactylidae
11      2    frog    89  leptodactylidae        0  leptodactylidae
12      2    frog    81  leptodactylidae        0  leptodactylidae
13      2    frog    89    dendrobatidae        0  leptodactylidae
14      3   horse    87         equidae1        2         equidae3
15      3  donkey    76         equidae2        2         equidae3
16      3   zebra    67         equidae3        2         equidae3
17      4    bird    54      psittacidae        0      psittacidae
18      4    bird    56      psittacidae        0      psittacidae
19      4    bird    34      psittacidae        0      psittacidae
20      5    bear    67              NaN        0              NaN
21      5    bear    54              NaN        0              NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help it works like a charm.

Comment: If I recall correctly, when you apply `max` to a object type column. It gets the most occuring string. Nothing to do with lexigographic. @ALollz

Comment: I agree with @ALollz! This is not a correct answer. This is a three steps process: (1) group rows; (2) count rows for each group; (3) merge back, sort by count and drop duplicates.

Comment: @Erfan no `max` always returns the largest value, never the most frequent value. Check with `pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1], 'B': ['a', 'a', 'b']}).groupby('A').B.transform('max')`

Comment: @ALollz thanks for pointing out. Editted my answer to correct output.